# SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION Message Never Disappears

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am showing login failure error if login is invalid, but even I refresh the page, the error never disappears.

```
<c:if test="${not empty SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION}">          
    <font color="red">
        Invalid username or password. Did you forget your password?
         <a href="#">I forgot</a>
    </font>
</c:if>
```

Is there another way to show when login is failed, or how I can fix that this error message won't be shown after refreshing the page or going another page?

Spring-security.xml:

```
<security:http  auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
<security:intercept-url pattern="/profile" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
<security:form-login
login-page="/clogin"
authentication-failure-url="/clogin?error=1"
default-target-url="/profile"
username-parameter="username"
/>
<security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="true" />

<security:csrf />
</security:http>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not checking if special parameter which is coming from failure url exists. In your case, `${not empty SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION}` is not always empty once you enter some values in your login page.

Try this one:

```
<c:if test="${param.auth eq 'failure'}">
      <div class="error">
         <font color="red">
        <c:out value="Username or password that you entered is invalid." /> . 
</font>
      </div>
</c:if>
```

and set your failure url as `/clogin?auth=failure` in spring-security.xml

`param.auth` means `auth` parameter in the failure url. `eq` means equals. So first check statement if `auth` parameter equals `failure` which will be coming from `=failure` from url.